# automatically create an item workflow, when a new item is created in the same list

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow

Automatically create  an item workflow, when a new item is created in the same list, so 2 item will display at the same time..

Is this possible in SP designer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not the perfectly fitting workflow for you, but you can see there the start options and how to set this.

https://blog.afrait.com/spd-workflow-to-concatenate-multiple-fields-en/

If it helps you, please give it a "vote up" or mark it as answer!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible. Open sharepoint designer. Under the **Action button** on Workflow tab there is action named **Create list item**.
Choose that action and than choose what columns should be populated/filled.

After you finish this, save workflow. It will appear at the lower left side of screen under the part named **List workflow**.
Click on your new workflow and when new window appears, at the right side of it check box named *Start workflow automatically when an item is created*.

Checking this your workflow will start each time item is created in your list by a person.
**Save and Publish your new workflow.**